# Using RegEx to Find a Block of Text

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to block a long string of unnecessary text that's on every page of a document.

Ex: `"36075 This is another page and this is the date March 4 2013"`

I know this must be very simple, but I'm hoping there is a way to block text verbatim. Is the only way to block this text by using a lot of `/d/s/w+/+` etc or is there is a way to say, `"match 36075 This is another page and this is the date March 4 2013"`.

This would be SO HELPFUL to know. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Is the text "*This is another page and this is the date*" fixed?

Comment: What do you mean by 'block a string' ? May be you can just use Regex.Replace("tofind", "") ?

Comment: Yes that text is fixed Maroun.

I mean that I want RegEx to find that set of words so that a text-to-speech app can skip over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue I was having. I didn't need to use RegEx. The program I was using has the functionality to match specific words or groups of words and pronounce them differently. What I discovered is that it will not match the words unless the word groups are input exactly the way the program typically reads them.

Ergo --> The channel saw

the end of the British hold over

Would have to be listed as one group for, "The channel saw" and a second group for "the end of the British hold over"

In addition, there were some numbers --> 11960_30_o_ho_ 
and if the program naturally read 119 and then 60_3 and then _o_ho_ then three strings would need to be input for each section.

A few frustrating hours later, problem solved :) Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote I assume you need to get leading numbers from string, to do it you just need to use this pattern: `^\d+` which from this input:

```
36075 This is another page and this is the date March 4 2013
```

will return this:

```
36075
```

For future, in case of such questions please provide example string and expected output. As well as what you have tried.

Comment: The only patterns I've tried are nearly wild guesses from about 3 hours of searching on here, which is why I didn't include any. I think it would only confuse the issue more.

I actually want to remove the digits and the text after it.

My desired output would be "36075 This is another page and this is the date March 4 2013".